# How can I click "File" button in the Menu Bar of Notepad using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using python for scripting. I want to save the file that I have edited in notepad. How can I achieve this in selenium?

I want to do the following using Selenium:
Click "File" > Click "Save as"

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:9999', desired_capabilities={"debugConnectToRunningApp": 'false', "app": r"C:/windows/system32/notepad.exe"})
window = driver.find_element_by_name("Notepad")
```

Comment: if its web element then have you tried using xpath :: //*[contains(text(),'Notepad)

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting, I found out is fairly simple:

```
window.find_element_by_name("File").click()
window.find_element_by_name("Save as").click()
```